# djangocms-text-ckeditor with django-filer

Tags: django-cms, django-filer

Ive been trying to get ckeditor working with the CMS. I cant seem to get inline images working
with filer. I'm trying to add an image from the list of cms plugins and can select the image from
the list of images already uploaded, but on finally clicking "ok" in the popup, the image appears
as "undefined" in the text area.

Any pointers as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: The expected thing would be, that a small thumbnail of the inserted image appears. Does thumbnailing otherwise work in your installation?

Comment: @stefanfoulis it did, yes. I did later figure out what was wrong, but cant remember ATM. Will update the question with what fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bizzare, but, changing the order of the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` fixed this. ie, having the ordering as below fixed the issue.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...

    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'cms',

    ...
)
```